# Программно подключится к точке доступа Wi-Fi

Tags: android, java

Извиняюсь за двойной пост, но прошлый был закрыт по причине невнимательности закрывшего!
Собственно, в андроид SDK есть только для включения/выключения Wi-Fi модуля и получения информации о сетях. А как самому **программно** подключится к определённой сети? Именно программно, а не кнопкой подключения!

Comment: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-to-connect-to-a-specific-wifi-network-in-android-programmatically)

Comment: [ВОТ ТУТ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8818290/how-do-i-connect-to-a-specific-wi-fi-network-in-android-programmatically) пример того как это сделать.